# Associative rule of subspaces and vector spaces: $(U+V) \cap W = U + (V \cap W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $U, V, W$ are subspaces of a vector space $X$ and if $U$ is a subspaces of $W$, then $$(U+V) \cap W = U + (V \cap W)$$

---

Do we need also that $V$ is a subspace of $W$? I can't see how to prove this otherwise.  This is typed up by my professor so it's definitely possible there's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality
$$ (U+V)\cap W=U+(V\cap W) \tag1$$
holds without the assumption that $V$ is a subspace of $W$, it is enough that $U\subseteq W$.

**Proof.** Let $z\in (U+V)\cap W$. Then $z\in W$ and $z=u+v$ for some $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.
Since $v=z-u$ and $u,z\in W$ we see that this $v$ is in $W$. Hence $v\in V\cap W$ and therefore
$z=u+v\in U+(V\cap W)$. On the other hand, if $z\in U+(V\cap W)$, then $z=u+v$ for some
$u\in U$ and $v\in V\cap W$. Since $U\subseteq W$ one has $u+v\in W$ and $u+v\in U+V$, i.e.,
$z\in (U+V)\cap W$.

**Example.** Let $X={\mathbb R}^3$ and
$$ U=\{ (a,0,0);\, a\in {\mathbb R}\}, \quad V=\{ (0,b,c);\, b, c\in {\mathbb R}\},\quad
\text{and}\quad W=\{ (a,b,0);\, a, b\in {\mathbb R}\}.$$
Then (1) holds although $V\not\subset W.$